# JDK not found on CentOS 6 x64

Tags: centos, centos6, jetty, java

I installed jetty on a CentOS 6 server, but when i try to reach a WAR example of jetty I get this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

yum says that the JDK 1.6 is already installed and when I run

`locate javac`

nothing relevant is returned.

I added `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin` to `$PATH`

but I think this is still JRE and not a JDK.

I downloaded and executed `java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux-x64.sh` but it outputs `Could not locate a suitable jar utility.`

Do someone know how could I install the Java development kit 1.6 on this server ?

EDIT : 
I updated JAVA_HOME and PATH and I still get the same error.
I added the following commands to my bash_profile :

```
export PATH=/usr/java/latest/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest/
```

But I get an unexpected EOF syntax error

EDIT 2 :

I installed `jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm` as the other weren't working, which generated new files in `/usr/java/`. unfortunately, after adding the new path to java it still doesn't work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel` as well.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! I never seen anywhere that I had to install this package as well

Comment: also, use /bin/java  instead of /jre/bin/java .

Answer (score 2):

So, main answer: once you've found out where javac is, your life will be better if you use the "alternatives" command to set the default javac and java, and then set JAVA_HOME to /usr. 
Here are simple instructions:
http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-switch-java-in-centos/

Now, let's try to find javac. I would expect it to be in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin - does that directory exist? If not, what do you have under /usr/java - is there a /usr/java/jdkxxxx there? If so, check /usr/java/jdkxxxx/bin.

Comment: after installing `jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm` and `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel`, I located javac in `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64`?

Comment: I set JAVA_HOME to this folder but nothing changes